# replacing pipe delimiter with tab or comma in java

Tags: java, regex, pipe, delimiter

I have to convert pipe delimited data into either tab delimited or comma delimited format.  I wrote the following method in java:

```
public ArrayList<String> loadData(String path, String fileName){
    File tempfile;
    try {//Read File Line By Line
        tempfile = new File(path+fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempfile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        int i = 0;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            strLine.replaceAll("\\|", ",");
            cleanedData.add(strLine);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("e for exception is:"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cleanedData;
}
```

The problem is that the resulting data is still pipe delimited.  Can anyone show me how to fix the code above, so that it returns either tab delimited or comma delimited data?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Strings in Java are immutable. The `replaceAll` method doesn't do in-place replacement. It returns a new string, which you have to re-assign back:

```
strLine = strLine.replaceAll("\\|", ",");
```

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't see that at all.

Comment: Still say the compiler needs to throw an error for calling a non-void method without assigning it's value to something, unless annotated.

Comment: @RohitJain bingo. +1.  But can you show how to replace it with tabs instead of commas also?

Comment: @CodeMed use "\t" instead of ",".